# Amazon S3 upload error: An exception occurred while uploading parts to a multipart upload

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a 30 GB file to Amazon S3 using the AWS PHP SDK.

```
require('../vendor/autoload.php');

use Aws\S3\MultipartUploader;
use Aws\Exception\MultipartUploadException;

$client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
'version' => 'latest',
'region'  => 'us-east-1'
]);

$bucket_name = 'Server3-27-SEP-2015';
$file_name   = 'S3_www_1443369605.zip';

$uploader = new MultipartUploader($client, $file_name, [
'bucket' => $bucket_name,
'key'    => $file_name,
'part_size' => '5368709120' // 5GB
]);

try {
    $result = $uploader->upload();
    echo "Upload complete \n";
} catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
    echo "Upload error: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

It works for files up to 7GB. When uploading the 30 GB file I am getting the following error after the script has run for about 2 hours:

---

An exception occurred while uploading parts to a multipart upload. The following parts had errors:
- Part 5: Error executing "UploadPart" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Server3-27-SEP-2015/S3_www_1443369605.zip?partNumber=5&uploadId=xE1ohuuvqnuLyNeU7.TO.BSI6.ld9nchWkoTdWgtS4EyF9rEoRtT3z8SSsaogu6A6u_tb4FPL.WDG056xusaiw--"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 55: SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)  (server): 100 Continue -
- Part 4: Error executing "UploadPart" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Server3-27-SEP-2015/S3_www_1443369605.zip?partNumber=4&uploadId=xE1ohuuvqnuLyNeU7.TO.BSI6.ld9nchWkoTdWgtS4EyF9rEoRtT3z8SSsaogu6A6u_tb4FPL.WDG056xusaiw--"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)  (server): 100 Continue -
- Part 2: Error executing "UploadPart" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Server3-27-SEP-2015/S3_www_1443369605.zip?partNumber=2&uploadId=xE1ohuuvqnuLyNeU7.TO.BSI6.ld9nchWkoTdWgtS4EyF9rEoRtT3z8SSsaogu6A6u_tb4FPL.WDG056xusaiw--"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 56: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)  (server): 100 Continue -
- Part 1: Error executing "UploadPart" on "https://s3.amazonaws.com/Server3-27-SEP-2015/S3_www_1443369605.zip?partNumber=1&uploadId=xE1ohuuvqnuLyNeU7.TO.BSI6.ld9nchWkoTdWgtS4EyF9rEoRtT3z8SSsaogu6A6u_tb4FPL.WDG056xusaiw--"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 55: SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 104 (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)  (server): 100 Continue -

---

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to find a solution for this